# Determine where function is differentiable

Tags: derivatives

Hi i have a problem with following assignment. I need to find where following function is differentiable. 
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^4+y^2}-|y|$$
I found somewhere that function is differentiable in point **a** if  all of it's partial derivative exist and are continuous in **a**.
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{4x^3}{2\sqrt{x^4+y^2}}$$
obviously continuous everywhere except **(0,0)**
$$\frac{df}{dy}=\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{x^4+y^2}}+/-1$$ same as above continuous everywhere except **(0,0)**
Now i have a problem with (0,0)i counted $$\frac{df}{dy}(0,0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h-|h|}{h}$$ so limes may be **0** or **2** so partial derivative doesn't exist? So differencial doesn't as well?

Comment: Better to use $\partial f /\partial y$ notation. By the way, you were a little careless with the $\pm 1$ business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: That $|y|$ term causes problems at each $(x_0,0), x_0\ne 0.$ As for $(0,0),$ show that both partial derivatives are $0.$ So if $Df(0,0)$ exists, it has to be the $0$ linear transformation. Go back to the definition of differentiable to see if this is possible.

Comment: I am clearly missing something, for x i can easily show that partial derivative  is zero, but for y i get that limes doesn't exist(left side 2 right 0) so derivative as well. In which place *|y|* cause problems? When i calculate *x* partial derivative i assume *y* is some const so it doesn't bother me, for *y* partial derivative i can split it into 2 sub-function for y greater than zero and less. But in zero i got it doesn't exist

Comment: No, $f(0,y) \equiv 0.$

Comment: Stupid mistake so partial derivative exists and i got it is differentiable in zero. You wrote i was careless with $\pm 1$, it's not true? I checked it with wolfram and get same : sgn(y).

Comment: when you use Wolfie, you're not doing mathematics. The result is is not sgn$(y)$, because sgn$(0)$ $=0.$ But $\partial f /\partial y$ does not exist along the $x$-axis except at $x=0.$ And no, $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0).$

Comment: $$f'(0,0)=\lim_{a,b\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a,b)-f(0,0)-(0*a+0*b)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\lim_{a,b\rightarrow 0}\frac {\sqrt{a^4+b^2}-|b|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\lim_{a,b\rightarrow 0}| \frac{a^4}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot (\sqrt{a^4+b^2}+|b|)}| \le | \frac{a^4}{|a|a^2} |=0$$ And could you help me understand why i have to consider $(x_{0},0)$ points individually

Comment: Nevermind i got it now, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Good job on $Df(0,0).$ I made a mistake there.